# Fade out a fragment later in reveal.js

Tags: reveal.js

I am trying to fade in an element, have it visible for a **range** of steps, and then hide it. Using `class="fragment current-visible"` or `class="fragment fade-in-then-out"` does not work as the fragment is visible for only one step. I tried using nested fragments together with the `data-fragment-index` attribute but nothing worked.

For example:

- Step 1 (empty slide):

- Step 2 (first item appears):

```
Item 1
```

- Step 3 (second item appears, first item still visible):

```
Item 1
Item 2
```

- Step 4 (first item disappears)

```
Item 2
```